# Covariance matrix of variables that sum to one?

Tags: probability, normal-distribution

Let $X_i \sim N(\mu_i , \sigma^2_i)$ and let $\sum_{i=1}^k X_i = 1$.

What is their joint distribution?

Comment: This problem is not well defined.

Comment: Why not, and what would be required/changed for it to be well-defined?

Comment: @Experthand:  Do you mean the distribution of $(X_1, \dots, X_k)$ conditional on $\sum_{i=1}^k X_i = 1$?

Comment: It is ill-defined because the answer depends on the joint distribution of the $X_i$ (before conditioning on their sum), not only on the marginal distributions you have specified.  It also depends on whether $k$ denotes the number of such $X_i$ or possibly is less than their number.